# Функция, возвращает функцию: print выводит <function ...> вместо значения

Tags: python-3.x

```
def newfunc(n):
    def myfunc(x):
        return x + n
    return myfunc
new = newfunc(100)  
print(new)
```

Выводит:

```
<function newfunc.<locals>.myfunc at 0x000001FF3E5A0B70>
```

Ожидаем выход число 200, но не в консоли.

В консоли все хорошо :

```
def newfunc(n):
    def myfunc(x):
        return x + n
    return myfunc
new = newfunc(100)  
new(200)
```

Comment: а какое ожидаемый был выход? в чем вопрос-то заключается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

функция *newfunc* возвращает **функцию**.

Поэтому и вывод print соответствующий.

Чтобы получить значение этой функции - нужно вызвать ее, например так

```
def newfunc(n):
    def myfunc(x):
        return x + n
    return myfunc
new = newfunc(100)  
print(new(100))
```

В этом случае выведется 200.